# Git pre-pushed object on remote server? git ls-tree

Tags: python, git, bash

I have a Atlassian Stash server for git.

I am looking to write a script that will run java code formatter as a pre-receive hook (before it pushes the changes to the repository).

So, what I am looking to do is **NOT** to do the work on the stash server itself rather perform the work on another server and send the status back (0 or 1) to the Stash server.

I have written the script in Python where it calls a cgi (python) script on the remote server with "ref oldrev newrev" as HTTP GET Method. Once I have the STDIN values (ref oldrev newrev) on a remote server, I created a dir, git init, git remote add origin URL, and git fetch (i even tried git pull) to get the latest contents/objects of a reporsitory in hoping to get the object that has not been pushed to the repository but its in a pre-pushed stage environment.

The hash or SHA key or "newrev" key of the object that is in the pre-pushed stage: 36ac63fe7b15049c132c310e1ee153e044b236b7

Now, when I run 'git ls-tree 36ac63fe7b15049c132c310e1ee153e044b236b7 Test.java' inside the directory I created above, it gives me error.

'fatal: not a tree object'

Now, My questions are:

How to get that object on a remote server?

What might be the git command that I run that will give me that object in that stage?

Is there any other way of doing this?

Does it make any sense of what I've asked above. Let me know if I am not clear and I will try to clear things up more.

Thanks very much in advanced for any/all the help?

Answer (score 0):

> java code formatter as a pre-receive hook

Don't do it. You're trying to run the equivalent of `git filter-branch` behind your developer's back.  Don't do it.

> Is there any other way of doing this?

If you want inbound code formatted in a particular way, validate the inbound files. If any aren't done right list them and reject the push.

> How to get that object on a remote server?

You can't fetch arbitrary objects, you can only fetch by ref (branch or tag) name.  The pre-receive hook runs before any refs have been updated, so no ref names the inbound commits.

Comment: Thanks for the response jthill. But I am looking for a "not normal" solution here to solve this since the problem I am facing isnt normal either.

I also know to do the code formatting and validating the inbound files and reject the push and I already have that running. But, I am looking to do this on a remote server, and **NOT** on the Stash server itself. 

Do you or anyone know how to create a temporary ref and point it to another SHA and different directory.

Comment: @MurtazaPitalwala Describe the problem please?  What are you trying to make go away here?  Reduce CPU load on the server, what?

Comment: The problem is that I have to figure out a way to perform java formatting checks and other checks before a commit is pushed to the master branch **On the remote server**, Not on the stash server. I am leaning towards that it is not possible as of now since the ref has not been pushed/committed.

One way I thought of:

1. Get/git cat the *.java files on the physical file system on the Stash server
2. then upload the file(s) to the remote server
3. Once the files are uploaded perform the work on the remote server
4. Send the response (0 or 1) back to the Stash server.